# Exception on stopping AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to stop my `AsyncTask` when the app exits, but I get the following exception. Where am I wrong? this is my code -

**I declare the variable-**

```
private DownloadFileAsync mTask;
```

**then in onDestroy-**

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.v("SERVICE", "Service killed");
    mTask.cancel(true);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

> 03-03 08:57:41.200: E/AndroidRuntime(22678): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop service com.exe.shark.NSOMUHBroadcastService@d58223c: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.exe.shark.NSOMUHBroadcastService$DownloadFileAsync.cancel(boolean)' on a null object reference

Comment: `mTask` is null. refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

try checking if `mTask` in not null

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.v("SERVICE", "Service killed");
    if(mTask != null) {
        mTask.cancel(true);
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: It still keeps running

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your `AsyncTask` has not been instantiated or run by the time your `Activity` is being destroyed. 
So you might have to check that `mTask` is not null.

You might also want to check if `mTask` is still running at the time the `Activity` is being destroyed by calling
`mTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING` .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `mTask` is not being set and is null. To start an `AsyncTask` do something like the following:

```
DownloadFileAsync mTask = new DownloadFileAsync (...parameters vary...);
mTask.execute(...parameters vary...);
```

It is not enough to just declare the task variable - you must explicitly start it as shown above. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for details.

I will also mention here that `mTask.cancel(true)` will not actually cancel your task unless you check for the cancel flag within the task and exit gracefully, but that is something you will have to program. See "Cancelling a task" is the referenced documentation above.